# Layout Design for Galaxy tab

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new in Andoid
I want to design layout for Galaxy tab along with other layout. I design four layout
Layout-small,large,xlarge and layout for normal. But When I am trying to check this in Galaxy tab the layout is stretched.
So how i develop the layout that run in Galaxy tab also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation



Low density Small screens QVGA 240x320 

res/layout-small-ldpi
res/layout-small-land-ldpi

Low density Normal screens WVGA400 240x400 (x432)

res/layout-ldpi
res/layout-land-ldpi

Medium density Normal screens HVGA 320x480

res/layout-mdpi
res/layout-land-mdpi

Medium density Large screens HVGA 320x480

res/layout-large-mdpi
res/layout-large-land-mdpi

High density Normal screens WVGA800 480x800 (x854)

res/layout-hdpi
res/layout-land-hdpi

Xoom (medium density large but 1280x800 res)

res/layout-xlarge
res/layout-xlarge-land
```