# ANDROID : Multiple resolution

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an app that support multiple resolutions. I have been through the http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html but couldn't find the solution.

The resolutions are :

1) 320x480 (Samsung Galaxy ACE)

2) 480x800 (Samsung Nexus S)

3) 600x1024 (Samsung Galaxy Tab 7in)

How do I classify the folder names for Layout and Drawable as well?

Currently I am using:-

For 320x480 : layout-mdpi, drawable-mdpi

For 480x800 : layout-hdpi, drawable-hdpi

For 600x1024 : layout-large, drawable-large

Only the 320x480 resolution is working fine.

Please help.

Comment: The dpi are maybe not related to the screen size. But I think there is a way to specifify the screen size directly. I saw there something in the sharlockactionbar source code.

Comment: @rekire - I just searched and checked..it's using same specifications.

Comment: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/library/res there they use a mix see the folder names

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8500793/1012284 BTW did U add support screen in manifest.xml?

Comment: @PadmaKumar - Yes I have added support screen in manifest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead using *xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, sdpi* try to use *small, normal, large, xlarge.*

Every device has it own density, sometimes large device having less density and vice versa, So just try to use drawble(outside category),  drawble-small,  drawble-normal,  drawble-large and layout(outside category), layout-small,
layout-normal, layout-large.

Comment: What names should I give to 480x800 and 600x1024 folders?

Comment: refer this too http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ScreenSizeQualifier.

Comment: @rekire - I guess it's more of a hit-n-trial now. I will update once I get through this.

Comment: For 600x1024 I used "layout-large-hdpi" and "drawable-large-hdpi" and it worked. Though don't know why for some reasons I was not able to get correct layout for Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.0 on 7inch Window on Eclipse so had to set the layouts on a 5.1in window.
Thanks @hotveryspicy !!!